# PHP function to get url from route

Tags: php, routes

I have this class:

```
class Route
{
    protected $routes = [
        "view_article" => "view/{articleUrl}",
        "edit_article" => "edit/{articleId}"
    ];
}
```

How can I make a function that returns the url replacing content inside brackets?
For example if I use this code:

`$route->getUrl('view_article', 'first-article');`

It should return: `view/first-article`

Comment: You need to use `preg_replace`

Comment: What have you tried? What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUrl($key, $value){
   $value = preg_replace('/[\[{\(].*[\]}\)]/U' , $value, $this->routes[$key]);
   return $value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I have multiple values?

Comment: For example: `"view_article" => "view/{category}/{pageUrl}"`, and the code: `$route->getUrl('view_article', 'news', 'first-article');`

Answer (score 0):

Then you should make a function that return your variable?

```
class Route {
    function getUrl($find, $replace) {
        $entry = isset($this->routes[$find]) ? $this->routes[$find]: false; 
        if($entry) {
            return str_replace(sprintf('{%s}', $find), $replace, $entry);
        } else {
            return return false;
        }
    }
}
```

something like that.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of solutions here:

`getUrl` below will accept the route name as the first parameter, then replace any placeholders with the subsequent variables. Not the best solution - you may have too many or too few variables. When using IDEs, there will be no parameter hinting.

```
class Route
{
    protected $routes = [
        "view_article" => "view/{articleUrl}",
        "edit_article" => "edit/{articleId}",
        "view_page" => "view/{articleId}/{pageName}"
    ];

    public function getUrl() {
        $arg_list = func_get_args();
        $route = $this->routes[$arg_list[0]];
        unset($arg_list[0]);
        foreach($arg_list as $arg) {
            $route = preg_replace('/{[^\}]+}/', $arg, $route, 1);
        }
        return $route;
    }
}
$route = new Route();
var_dump($route->getUrl('view_page', '17', 'hello_world')); //'view/17/hello_world'
```

An alternative approach is to use an array of arguments and `str_replace` the key=>value pairs:

```
class Route
{
    protected $routes = [
        "view_article" => "view/{articleUrl}",
        "edit_article" => "edit/{articleId}",
        "view_page" => "view/{articleId}/{pageName}"
    ];

    public function getUrl($routeName, $args) {

        $route = $this->routes[$routeName];
        foreach($args as $key => $value) {
            $route = str_replace(sprintf('{%s}', $key), $value, $route);
        }
        return $route;
    }
}
$route = new Route();
var_dump($route->getUrl('view_page', ['articleId' => 17, 'pageName' => 'hello_world'])); //'view/17/hello_world'
```

In both cases, be sure to include additional checks (route exists, all the variables have been replaced, etc).